# grunt: cdnify doesn't do anything

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman-generator

I have created an AngularJS application using Yeoman. It also uses the *cdnify* task that shoud transform **bower_components/angular/angular.js** into **//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js**. The generated **index.html** contains the following code:

```
<!-- build:js scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

There is also a task that combines, minifies and uglifies all the scripts, so these scripts are combined into a single **vendor.js** file. To avoid **jquery.js** and **angular.js** to be included in this process, I changed it into:

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<!-- build:js scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

When I run **grunt serve:dist** the cdnify task is ran and generates the following output:

```
Running "cdnify:dist" (cdnify) task
Going through dist/404.html, dist/index.html to update script refs
```

My **bower.json** looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "myAmazingAngularApp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "~1.11.0",
    "angular": "1.2.x",
    "bootstrap": "~3.1.1",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.10.0"
  }
}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I would think it should work out-of-the-box, so I suspect it's a bug...

There is also a **.bowerrc** file that has the following content:

```
{
    "directory": "app/bower_components"
}
```

I tried changing this setting to `"directory`: `bower_components"` when running `grunt cdnify`, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Can you check configuration for `"directory"` in .bowerrc or bower.json - should be `"bower_components"` in your case.

Comment: I have checked the `directory` and it is listed in my `.bowerrc`. My `bower.json` doesn't contain a directory entry. I haven't modified this data.

Comment: in .bowerrc your directory configuration looks exactly like this: `"directory": "bower_components"` ? Could you also show us your configuration for cdnify task in your Gruntfile.js?

Comment: The default Yeoman generator generates a `.bowerrc` that contains `"directory" = "app/bower_componentents"`. The actual `href` in the `index.html` file contains `<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>`.

To install the Bower components I used the generated setting, but when running `grunt cdnify` I also tried to change the .bowerrc, so it only contains `"directory"="bower_components"`.

Unfortunately... It didn't help... But the file that is generated by Yeoman's Angular generator seems to be wrong anyway.

Comment: which version of `grunt-google-cdn` do you have in your package config? try to update to ~0.4.0. Remember that cdnify in default yeoman configuration updates html files from dist directory.

Comment: Everything seems fine. Has anyone tried the Yeoman angular scaffolder and got it to work?

Comment: no there is an open issue: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/266 :(